# Access instance in other modules

Tags: python

I have a class instance I want to access in other modules. This class loads config values using configParser to update an class instance `__dict__` attribute as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620602/creating-a-class-with-all-the-elements-specified-in-a-file-using-configparser):

I want to access this instance in other module. The instance is only created in the `main.py` file where it has access to the required parameters, which come via command line arguments.

I have three files: `main.py`, `config.py` and `file.py`. I don't know the best way to access the instance in the `file.py`. I only have access to it in `main.py` and not other modules.

I've looked at the following answers, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10942831/import-instance-of-class-from-a-different-module) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888809/accessing-class-instance-from-another-module-python) but they don't fully answer my scenario.

```
#config.py
class Configuration():
    def __init__(self, *import_sections):
        #use configParser, get config for relevant sections, update self.__dict__

#main.py
from config import Configuration
conf = Configuration('general', 'dev')
# other lines of code use conf instance ... e.g. config.log_path in log setup

#file.py
#I want to use config instance like this:
class File():
    def __init__(self, conf.feed_path):
       # other code here...
```

Options considered:

1. **Initialise Configuration in config.py module**

   In `config.py` after class definition I could add:

   ```
   conf = Configuration('general', 'dev')
   ```

   and in `file.py` and `main.py`:

   ```
   from config import conf
   ```

   but the `general` and `dev` variables are only found in `main.py` so doesn't look like it will work.
2. **Make Configuration class a function**

   I could make it a function and create a module-level dictionary and import     data into other modules:

   ```
   #config.py
   conf = {}
   def set_config(*import_section):
       # use configParser, update conf dictionary
       conf.update(...)
   ```

   This would mean referring to it as `config.conf['log_path']` for example. I'd prefer `conf.log_path` as it's used multiple times.
3. **Pass via other instances**

   I could pass the conf instance as parameters via other class instances from `main.py`, even if the intermediate instances don't use it. Seems very messy.
4. **Other options?**

   Can I use Configuration as an instance somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing your `Configuration` class into a [`Borg`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531-singleton-we-dont-need-no-stinkin-singleton-the-bo/), you are guaranteed to get a common state from wherever you want. You can either provide initialization through a specific `__init__`:

```
#config.py
class Configuration:
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self, *import_sections):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
        if not import_sections: # we are not initializing this time
            return
        #your old code verbatim
```

initialization is donne as usual with a `c = config.Configuration('general','dev')` and any call to `conf = config.Configuration()` will get the state that `c` created.

or you can provide an initialization method to avoid tampering with the shared state in the `__init__`:

```
#config.py
class Configuration:
    __shared_state = {}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state

    def import(self, *import_sections):
        #your old __init__
```

that way there is only one meaning to the `__init__` method, which is cleaner.

In both cases, you can get the shared state, once initialized, from anywhere in your code by using `config.Configuration()`.

Comment: I love Python for this pattern. We don't need no stinking singletons.